# How to write/save a lot of data to a node js server?

Tags: c#, node.js, post, backend

I have a c# software that sends a lot of data stored in collections to a node.js backend, at the moment I encode the data to base64 on the c# end and send it with POST, stored in the body.

```
            {
                let buff = Buffer.from(req.body.systeminfo, 'base64');
                fs.writeFileSync(file, buff.toString('utf-8'));
            }
```

This is the code on node, but it messes up the data, at the end, especially larger files, become corrupted with characters like "�" instead of actual data, what should I do?

Also the server should be able to manage data send from multiple users at the same time.

EDIT: Should I convert the data into files and then send files instead?

Comment: you donot need to convert buffer to string, write in buffer. `fs.writeFileSync(file, buff);`

Comment: Something doesn't match here.  You send arbitrary binary data encoded in base64, but then reinterpret that data as a utf-8 encoded string.  Is the buffer really a utf-8 encoded string?  I suspect not.  Did you just mean to write the binary buffer data directly to the file?

Comment: It isn't binary data, it's text, sorry for not specifying.

Comment: Also, your question is _how to send data to a server_ but if `buff` is correct, then you've already sent the data to the server.  Your problem seems to be about how to write that data to a file.  Please edit your question, if that's the case.

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry for making such stupid mistakes, I thought I needed to change the entire way I send the data, not just how we process it.

Comment: @ChillSheep Give an example of a small buffer that arrived correctly but got written to the file with a �.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/bsRUyDc5 I translated it to English for context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of sending the data as text, I've sent it all as an archive.

```
let mainFile = req.files.file;
mainFile.mv(path);
```

The C# end

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                //Code
                client.UploadFile(url, filePath);
                client.Dispose();
            }
```